# What are the rcu_sched and rcu_bh?

Tags: kernel, process

I've found 2 processes shown below using `ps -aux`

```
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:23   0:06 [rcu_sched]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    11:23   0:00 [rcu_bh]
root      6267  0.0  0.0  12944  1036 pts/0    S+   14:36   0:00 grep --color=auto rcu
```

I understand the concept behind RCU(Read, Copy, Update) I just some clarification on what the 2 processes precisely do as I'm struggling to find online documentation. Can anyone advise?

Comment: there is way to much for me to understand but you may find answers [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/RCU/whatisRCU.txt)

Comment: The new visibility of RCU processing https://lwn.net/Articles/518953/